# Django Admin CSRF Cookie issue

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have a website with django admin panel it is working fine but what i see that on refreshing the forms in the admin panel the csrf cookie is not regenerating it is showing the same.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, can you elaborate your issue a bit more?

Comment: @Hybrid: Actually i am scanning my website admin panel which is auto created through django so after i scanned it it is showing the CSRF countermeasures vulnerability.
So i thought that it is due to the same csrf token for one form it is not refreshing once page refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Note that the CSRF token is **not** regenerated on page load. It is normal to see the same token used repeatedly.

In Django, the CSRF token is set to a random value for each session - it is also known as "session independent nonce". Other sites will not be able to access the CSRF token value in the cookie. If you create a new session, a new CSRF token will be used.

When you submit a form, Django will check that the CSRF token submitted in the form data matches the one in the cookie.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/csrf/#how-it-works for more information.